# Possible Nested case statement or IF statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query in sql server 2008. 
It gets the sum of the quantity field which has been converted 
 based on what material group and UOM it belongs to 
The query includes the following field

```
SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN A.[case_MaterialGroup] LIKE '%OIL%'
                      AND A.[case_UOM] = 'KG' THEN A.[case_quantity] * 0.2
                 WHEN A.[case_MaterialGroup] LIKE '%VOL%'
                      AND A.[case_UOM] = 'ACR' THEN A.[case_quantity] / 2.4711
                 WHEN A.[case_ProductDetails] LIKE '%FODDER RAPE%'
                      OR A.[case_ProductDetails] LIKE '%STUBBLE TURNIP%' THEN A.[case_quantity] / 3
                 WHEN @tonage LIKE '%' + A.[Case_ProductArea] + '%'
                      AND A.[case_UOM] = 'KG' THEN A.[case_quantity] / 1000
                 WHEN @kilo LIKE '%' + A.[Case_ProductArea] + '%'
                      AND A.[case_UOM] = 'TO' THEN A.[case_Quantity] * 1000
                 ELSE A.[case_quantity]
            END AS NUMERIC)) AS Quantity
```

The code above works fine, it calculates a SUM for Quantity based on the material group and UOM (Unit of Measure. 
Now I would like to be able to do another test on the Quantity value before the sum is calculated

```
Cast (Case When A.[case_Bltp] = 'RE' then Quantity * -1<br/>
           when A.[case_Bltp] = 'G2' then 0  <br/>
           else Quantity end as numeric) as Quantity, <br/>
```

And do the SUM on the final value of Quantity.

Do I have to write a really long case statement or is there a way i can incorporate the two case statements? 
Thanks 
Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this,
I did a nested Case statement and added one of the options to the where statement 
If anyone wants to see it, I can add it on Friday